# What is the runtime effeciency of this function

Tags: performance, runtime, analysis

given the following:

```
    void foo(Bar[] barArray){
        barArray.sort();
    }
```

What is the big O?
I would assume that as we have no knowledge of the barArray.sort() method's runtime we treat it as a basic operation and hence the runtime efficiency of our function is O(1). Am I correct? And am I correct for the right reasons? And if I am not correct, why?

Comment: "Am I correct?" - no. If you don't know what sorting method is used there is no way to know the big O.

Comment: So I assume the correct answer in that case would be O(1) + O(sort)?

Comment: @officialhopsof First of all, O(sort) is not very meaningful, yes? Also, you need to drop the nondominant terms in asymptotic analysis. For example, O(1) + O(N), based on the runtime order N has more operations than 1 which is a constant, so the runtime is O(N) not O(1). You need to understand this point: always drop the nondominant terms.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't know the runtime of .sort(), you need to guess what that is, which is not ideal, because in time complexity analysis, you want to get as tight a bound as you can. However, you can base your reasoning on some common sorting algorithms like merge sort, quick sort, bubble sort, etc. What are their runtimes? You won't find O(1), because at the minimum you have a runtime that starts at O(N), unless you're talking about the best case scenario, which is good for school, but outside of that, we mostly care about the worst and average case scenarios.

Forget N for a moment, you should only use N when there's zero confusion about what N could be. Instead, let's treat this problem as a simple math exercise:

`a = length of the array`

Most sorting algorithms have you do some comparisons and then swap elements. You're doing this for every element from 1 to a, which means `a` operations. What does that leave you? O(a) runtime which means no matter how large `a` is, the algorithm is running in the order of O(a). This gives you an idea how fast or slow the algorithm is. It's similar to saying you're spending about "2 figures" (somewhere around hundreds) or "3 figures" (thousands) or whatever a month. It's a mental paradigm.

Going back to the sorting algorithm, can it do better than O(N)? Rather than handling every element in N, can we split N in half? This is a super common idea in computer science. Splitting the problem into subproblems usually means you're working with logarithms. O(logN) vs O(N), the former is more efficient.

*Alternatively*, for JS, you could use `console.time()` to estimate the runtime although there's been some questions around the accuracy of that method.

```
// O(1) fn
console.time();
function simpleSum(x, y) {
 return x + y;
}
console.timeEnd();
```

How does this compare to the `foo` fn?